# Need clarification about flowtype "exact Union Types"

Tags: flowtype

I don't understand how Unions work.

#### Doc reference

see this [doc example](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions-with-exact-types) about `exact Union Types`

#### Problem

Code below will throw a flow error on `item.rocks`:

```
/* @flow */

type MoutainType = {|
  rocks: boolean,
|};

type OceanType = {|
  waves: boolean,
|};

type HolidayType = MoutainType | OceanType;


const haveHoliday = (item: HolidayType) => {
  return item.rocks; //----------------> Error (but shouldn't)
}
```

### Try yourself

[See live demo](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCycArhgIYCWAdgCq4EC8YA3gD6phgBOcAxgGsAzgC4wAIzhwYectQA0qNgF8A3Omz4wAeT6y6DMM3acwCcgDc8oiVJlzFK9ZkMAJaZQAm5LPS3NiMioDLTYdPTk-PGdUPjhqIQwwAAtLPHcYLx8jMAAKSgw8AFsxDKzfBgBKIwA+VlNuPAwSbmowAuKAOl5BIVUwYGAAWhHRsfGhuoBRbl5uPPEyMCFk0hhPagByDErUZXRUIA)

Comment: Your current set up means it could be either type, but only one of them has a `rocks` property. Flow errors because it is telling you that the property doesn't always work. Are expecting `HolidayType` to be an object with _both_? If so maybe you wanted https://flow.org/en/docs/types/intersections/, not union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `HolidayType` to be an union of the types `MountainType` or `HolidayType`.  Flow needs to be able to determine which type it is dealing with before it will allow you to access an exclusive member property without throwing an error.

If you test for the `rocks` property before attempting to access it, Flow will then be able to determine which type is in play.

```
const haveHoliday = (item: HolidayType) => {
  if (typeof item.rocks !== 'undefined') {
      // Flow now knows that this must be a MountainType
      return item.rocks;
  }
}
```

Look at the docs for [Disjoint Unions](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions) and see if there is a literal value that you can use as the selector for type, and that gives you a more natural code path e.g.

```
type MountainType = {
  terrain: 'rocks'
}

type OceanType = {
  terrain: 'waves'
}

type HolidayType = MountainType | OceanType

const haveHoliday = (item: HolidayType): boolean => {
  return item.terrain === 'rocks'
}
```